# Objective-C Private Property Inheritance

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, inheritance

I just wanted to make sure my understanding of property inheritance was correct. I'm currently trying to make a subclass of a UIViewController. In my UIViewController all my outlets and such are declared in the implementation section like so:

```
@interface BaseClass()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *scoreLabel;

@end
```

Thus those properties are then private, correct? Now when I try and make a subclass and access those properties using my getters and setters, I cannot access them from my subclass. Is the proper form to redeclare those properties again in my subclass' implementation section, like so?

```
@interface SubClass()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *scoreLabel;

@end
```

I guess I am ok with doing it this way, but then I feel like it ruins the purpose of inheritance. What is the proper way/what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are "ok with doing it this way" **provided** you never directly reference the properties backing variable. What you are doing is creating two distinct properties each with their own backing variable. However due to overriding any reference to the property in an instance of `SubClass`, even if from a method defined in `BaseClass` will reference the subclasses property. However if in a `BaseClass` method you directly reference the property backing variable it will not change the property value of a `SubClass` instance... See @InsertWittyName answer for other approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would declare the property in the public interface for the `BaseClass` - I don't see any reason to put them in a class extension.

```
@interface BaseClass : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *scoreLabel;

@end

@interface SubClass : BaseClass

// No need to redeclare the property as you're inheriting it.

@end
```

**[EDIT]**

If you must use the class extension then you could use a private header to achieve the same.

**Public** header for BaseClass (BaseClass.h)

```
@interface BaseClass : UIViewController

@end
```

**Private** header for BaseClass (BaseClass-Private.h)

```
@interface BaseClass ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *scoreLabel;

@end
```

**Public** header for SubClass (SubClass.h)

```
#import "SubClass.h"

@interface SubClass : BaseClass

@end
```

Implementation of SubClass (SubClass.m)

```
#import "BaseClass-Private.h"

@implementation SubClass

@end
```

Comment: This makes sense. It's just that in the lecture series I've been following, the UI properties have always been put in the class extension, so I wasn't sure if that was just common practice or not. Would you be able to comment on this?

Comment: It's a personal decision I would say, some people like to put IBOutlets in class extensions as they're an implementation detail, others put them in the public interface. I'll edit and add info on how to do this while keeping them in the class extensions.